# Why removing royalty info on burn in Openzeppeling ERC721 Royalties extension?

Tags: nft, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts, burn, royalties

In https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/783ac759a902a7b4a218c2d026a77e6a26b6c42d/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol#L34 we have

```
function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
    super._burn(tokenId);
    _resetTokenRoyalty(tokenId);
}
```

Why resetting royalty info before burning as once burnt there's no way to use or transfer this token?

I can't find a good reason and it doesn't seem to be required in the EIP https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *reset* can be misleading, as you can see in [ERC2981.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/fb950c616694a6fb213fb1e784fadbfed4ec394c/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol#L115) that is a `sclear` operation (or `delete` in Solidity):

```
/**
 * @dev Resets royalty information for the token id back to the global default.
 */
function _resetTokenRoyalty(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
    delete _tokenRoyaltyInfo[tokenId];
}
```

That action has two main effects: freeing data from the chain and avoiding future inconsistencies.

**Freeing data**

Deleting data from the global storage is a best practice to keep the global state of the chain as clean as possible. To incentivize developers to apply this practice, the sender is refunded 15.000 gas from the overall transaction's cost.

`selfdestruct` and `sclear` are currently the only two EVM operations that refund gas instead of consuming it.

From the [yellow paper, page 27](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf):

> **sclear**: 15000 Refund given (added into refund counter) when the storage value is set to zero from non-zero.
>
> **selfdestruct**: 24000 Refund given (added into refund counter) for self-destructing an account.

**Avoiding inconsistencies**

As [Julissa DC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/80107/julissa-dc) already noted in another answer, the [current OpenZeppelin's implementation of EIP721](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ae54e6de1d77c60881e4c85ffbdb7f9d76b71efe/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol) allows the minting of burned tokens. Minting and burning are not part of the standard, so this can be done without breaking shared rules. If they want otherwise, it's up to each developer to override that behavior in their smart contract.

About [ERC721Royalty.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ae54e6de1d77c60881e4c85ffbdb7f9d76b71efe/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol), it is an optional extension to [ERC721.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ae54e6de1d77c60881e4c85ffbdb7f9d76b71efe/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol), so deleting royalties information regarding a token also ensures that, if a burned token is minted again, it will not have royalty information already in place, causing potential leaks of funds to previous receiver account.

Comment: I read on other answer that it prevents issues in case of reminting. Could you tell me more about this part?

Comment: I added more info about the reminting behavior (it's intended, I can't agree with that choice, but it's not a bug).

Answer (score 1):

As a security measure and to free space, more on the later [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32419/is-refunded-gas-for-freed-storage-given-to-the-contract-the-allocator-or-t). Now back to the security reasoning, as you can see nothing prevents you from re-minting a `tokenId` after it was burned, and someone could mint a burned tokenId that had royalty information in place, causing some fund leaks to the previous receiver account.

Disclaimer: I'm the one who made that commit.

Comment: Interesting topic, and thanks for your work :) A question: minting and burning are not part of the EIP721, shouldn't the most intuitive and safest implementation avoid allowing minting again a burned token? There are specific reasons to permit that instead?

Comment: Thats a great question, you are right is up to the developer how to mint and burn according to the EIP721, and thats why the implementation includes`_beforeTokenTransfer` and `_afterTokenTransfer` hooks for the developer using the contracts to include any behaviour before or after the transaction, not only that, both `mint` and `burn` are virtual so the developer overrides them if they need to. Unless you have extra data, like not deleted royalties, attached to it there is not a problem with re-minting a deleted token.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. My worries arise from the expectations that a `burn` method sets in the user's mind more than from code. Up now, talking about burning, I always meant that _the burned_ could not _resurrect_ later in any case. I used burn operations to generate _proofs-of-burn_, obtaining something in return for that sacrifice, off-chain or on-chain. The current implementation seems a bit counterintuitive: I can _really burn_ a token sending a simple `transfer` to address `0x0`, but if I use the dedicated `burn` I didn't really finish the job and I need to implement it by myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not written in a comprehensive enough way compered to Giuseppe's one. I can't decide what to chose... Plus I don't really understand the reminting part. How can this be possible? Burning is the end to me. How if you have something exchanged for the burn?

Comment: Plus this bounty is looking for reputable sources. I know you wrote the code, but that's not what we call a reputable source. It requires an article, reference to a paper (whatever the colour) or a security audit, something not only based on one's opinion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dont worry @NicolasMasart I just answer to let you know, not to win the bounty, I even upvoted his answer because it was more comprehensive  to read.

Comment: I added information provided by Julissa to the response. About sources, I cannot think of a more reputable source than the person that wrote the code ;) About the bounty, it's not a problem for me either, the real goal is to provide a satisfying answer to the question.